# Why is This code set up for FireStore uploading the data to the Realtime database when not referenced

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to convert my code so that it would upload the data to the Firestore database since its better for what I need.

```
private void uploadData(final String titl, final String description) {
    // show the progress dialog box
    pd.setMessage("Publishing Post");
    pd.show();
    final String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String filepathname = "Posts/" + "post" + timestamp;
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    // initalising the storage reference for uploading the data
    StorageReference storageReference1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(filepathname);
    storageReference1.putBytes(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // getting the url of image uploaded
            Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            while (!uriTask.isSuccessful()) ;
            String downloadUri = uriTask.getResult().toString();
            if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                HashMap<Object, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("uid", uid);
                hashMap.put("uname", name);
                hashMap.put("uemail", email);
                hashMap.put("udp", dp);
                hashMap.put("title", titl);
                hashMap.put("description", description);
                hashMap.put("uimage", downloadUri);
                hashMap.put("ptime", timestamp);
                hashMap.put("plike", "0");
                hashMap.put("pcomments", "0");

                FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").add(data)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(PostBlogActivity.this, "Published", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            title.setText("");
                            des.setText("");
                            image.setImageURI(null);
                            imageuri = null;
                            startActivity(new Intent(PostBlogActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                            PostBlogActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(PostBlogActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Honestly I don't know why its doing this since it has no reason to.
I also try doing it this way as well

```
private void uploadData(final String titl, final String description) {
    // show the progress dialog box
    pd.setMessage("Publishing Post");
    pd.show();
    final String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String filepathname = "Posts/" + "post" + timestamp;
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    // initalising the storage reference for uploading the data
    StorageReference storageReference1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(filepathname);
    storageReference1.putBytes(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // getting the url of image uploaded
            Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            while (!uriTask.isSuccessful()) ;
            String downloadUri = uriTask.getResult().toString();
            if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                HashMap<Object, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("uid", uid);
                hashMap.put("uname", name);
                hashMap.put("uemail", email);
                hashMap.put("udp", dp);
                hashMap.put("title", titl);
                hashMap.put("description", description);
                hashMap.put("uimage", downloadUri);
                hashMap.put("ptime", timestamp);
                hashMap.put("plike", "0");
                hashMap.put("pcomments", "0");

                FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document(timestamp).set(data)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(PostBlogActivity.this, "Published", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                title.setText("");
                                des.setText("");
                                image.setImageURI(null);
                                imageuri = null;
                                startActivity(new Intent(PostBlogActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                                PostBlogActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        });

            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(PostBlogActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I've copied what the tutorial says inside of android studio however that doesn't work, I am using the free version right now however that shouldn't stop me from writing to the database. It gives no errors or warnings that what I have done is wrong so that it would upload to the Realtime database instead. I have read my code to see if I have referenced the Realtime database by mistake however that piece of code is all what accesses and writes to the database. Though if my code was wrong I would expect it to crash and not upload the data to another database.

Comment: It's really hard to help with "doesn't work". Locally debugging the code and sharing the results makes it much more likely that someone can help. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document(timestamp).set(data) <-- thats the problem, since all the code works however its uploading to the wrong database

Comment: While both Realtime Database and Firestore are part of Firebase, they have completely separate APIs. There is no way that line of code will write to the Realtime Database.

Comment: So you basically say that the code in your question adds data to the Realtime Database rather than in Firestore? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).